# Spring Integration TCP - Initiate handshake with a message before sending data

Tags: sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I am using @MessagingGateway to send data to to server. I configured a AbstractClientConnectionFactory and a @ServiceActivator for my outbound gateway.

In order to send data to my server, I need to send a handshake message when the connection is initiated. If the response from server is the response that I expect for the handshake, then I send meaningful data. My initial solution is

`if (gateway.handshake(HANDSHAKE).equals(HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE))
    gateway.sendData(data);`

This is not so good when i am scaling up because I have doubled my calls over tcp as I only need to send send handshake on connection initiation and not every time. Also, I plan on keeping the connection alive.

So on connection initiation, how can I have this custom handshake implemented?

```
@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientCF() {
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpNetClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);

    tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSerializer(new serializerDeserializer());
    tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new serializerDeserializer());
    tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
    tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
    return tcpNetClientConnectionFactory;

}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcp")
public MessageHandler tcpOutGate(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway gate = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    gate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return gate;
}


@Bean
public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Connection Interceptors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-interceptors).

> Connection factories can be configured with a reference to a TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain. Interceptors can be used to add behavior to connections, such as negotiation, security, and other setup. No interceptors are currently provided by the framework but, for an example, see the InterceptedSharedConnectionTests in the source repository.
>
> The HelloWorldInterceptor used in the test case works as follows:
>
> ...

While there are no standard interceptors in the framework, there are [test cases that show how to use them for an initial handshake, for example here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/TcpSendingMessageHandlerTests.java#L904)
and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/InterceptedSharedConnectionTests.java).

The tests are more complex than you need because they test multiple nested interceptors.

The [hello world test interceptors](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/HelloWorldInterceptor.java#L35) send `Hello` and expect `World!` when the socket is first opened. They implement the handshake for both the client and server side.

Comment: The hello world example provided me with the exact thing I needed. As a follow up, I started working on connection pooling as I intended on. I stated using CachingClientConnectionFactory, but it doesn't fit my requirements. I need to enable connection pooling without setting singleUse to true.

Comment: I see documentation for CachingClientConnectionFactory, and I see "Connection factory that caches connections from the underlying target factory. The underlying factory will be reconfigured to have singleUse=true in order for the connection to be returned to the cache after use. Users should not subsequently set the underlying property to false, or cache starvation will result." Is there no other implementation I can use to set up a pool of connections that are always alive, so that I don't intercept each connection with the negotiation interceptor that I just added?

Comment: The `single use` there is not real - it's just a signal to the using classes to "close" the socket after use - which returns it to the cache - it doesn't actually close. The cached connection is itself an interceptor and `close()` simply does `this.pool.releaseItem(getTheConnection())`. Plus, it **has** to be single-use in order for the underlying factory to hand out new connections each time one is requested. If single-use is `false` only one connection is available.

Comment: Thats right and I'd want to not close the socket after use. I feel like CachingClientConnectionFactory is not the answer for my problem. What I need is to have a pool of keep alive connections so that I can send high volume of data over tcp. I feel like I can use "Collaborating Outbound and Inbound Channel Adapters" for high throughput instead of a regular gateway and CachingClientConnectionFactory. Spring integration has "tcp-client-server-multiplex" project that I can refer to. Do you think I am moving in the right direction?

Comment: What tou want is exactly what CCCF does. Just try it. The socket does not close; when the channel adapter "closes" the connection, it is left open and returned to the pool instead.

Comment: I tried it again. It does work the way I wanted it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: CCCF does one thing that I fail to understand, ideal connections sitting in the pool die after ~8 hours.  Is there anyway this behavior can be altered? Maybe I don’t want to keep an ideal connection in the pool for more than 15 mins.

Comment: However, normally, the server side will close idle connections after some time. We will detect that the next time the connection is used, and remove it from the pool.

Comment: Is there a way to set a maximum wait time for a thread to wait for a connection from the pool?

Comment: See `CachingClientConnectionFactory.setConnectionWaitTimeout()`.