# Spring integration on reconnect TCP send handshake

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I'm trying to use the ClientMode on the TcpSendingMessageHandler to auto-reconnect the connection. This connection needs to be kept open so it's important to implement a reconnect function.

```
private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
        String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
        Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");
        Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
        String hostPort = host + port;

        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter messageHandler = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        cf.setLeaveOpen(true);
        TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain fc = new TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain();

        HelloWorldInterceptorFactory factory = new HelloWorldInterceptorFactory();
        fc.setInterceptors(new TcpConnectionInterceptorFactory[] { factory} );

        cf.setInterceptorFactoryChain(fc);
        cf.setDeserializer(new CustomSerializerDeserializer());
        messageHandler.setErrorChannel(errorChannel);
        messageHandler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        messageHandler.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
        TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        handler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        handler.setClientMode(true);
        handler.setRetryInterval(5000);
        IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(handler);
        IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
                this.flowContext
                        .registration(flow)
                        .addBean(cf)
                        .id(hostPort + ".flow")
                        .register();
        MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();
        this.subFlows.put(hostPort, inputChannel);
        return inputChannel;
    }
```

Unfortinily I need to send a handshake after the connection socket has been opened.

I tried to add a Message interceptor described in this post ([Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632414/spring-integration-tcp-initiate-handshake-with-a-message-before-sending-data)) but when the connection socket is restored it doesn't enter the interceptor.

I get this warning when the socket is restored:

```
HelloWorldInterceptor        : No publisher available to publish TcpConnectionOpenEvent [source=HelloWorldInterceptor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is coming out of the interceptor because the factory was not initialized properly.

You need to add `.addBean()` for the interceptor factory too.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments an alternative to the interceptors is just to use an event listener.

I just tested with this and see no problems:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So65899947Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So65899947Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return f -> f.handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1234))
                .clientMode(true)
                .retryInterval(5000));
    }

}

@Component
class InitialSender {

    private final IntegrationFlow flow;

    InitialSender(IntegrationFlow flow) {
        this.flow = flow;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void opened(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        this.flow.getInputChannel().send(new GenericMessage<>("Hello there", 
                Collections.singletonMap(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, event.getConnectionId())));
    }

}
```

```
$ nc -l 1234
Hello there
^C

$ nc -l 1234
Hello there
^C

$ nc -l 1234
Hello there
^C

$ nc -l 1234
Hello there
^C

$ nc -l 1234
Hello there
^C
```

**EDIT2**

Same results for me when I changed it to use a gateway...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class So65899947Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So65899947Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return f -> f.handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1234))
                .clientMode(true)
                .retryInterval(5000));
    }

}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "flow.input")
interface Gate {

    void handShake(@Payload String message, @Header(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID) String conn);

}

@Component
class InitialSender {

    private final Gate gate;

    InitialSender(Gate gate) {
        this.gate = gate;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void opened(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        this.gate.handShake("Hello there", event.getConnectionId());
    }

}
```

Comment: I create the TcpNetClientConnectionFactory dynamic for multiple connections. Everything works fine including the interception if I use a gateway to send the handshake message. I want this handshake message to be sent automatically again after the connection socket is restored.

Comment: I didn't notice the `addBean()` and that the warning is coming out of the interceptor. The problem is that the interceptor factory is not initialized with the event publisher. It needs an `addBean()` too.

Comment: This is working normally, I asked the wrong question I think. When the socket is created I want to send a message automatically (this is the handshake). So can this be done or can I subscribe to a channel so I can be notified the socket is started?

Comment: Instead of using the interceptors, you can simply add an `@EventListener` method to receive `TcpConnectionOpenEvent`s. Use `getConnectionId()` on the event and send a message to the outbound adapter with the connection id in the `IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID` header.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! This indeed does the trick! The only strange thing is when I terminate the server connection for a second time it doesn't reconnect anymore. The first time the TCPconnection class detects this fine, restores the socket and I receive the event. The second time it doesn't try to reconnect. I don't see anything strange in the debug logging. Is this a know problem?

Comment: I am not aware of any problems like that; I just tested it and bounced the server a bunch of times and it reconnected every time. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: It works indeed! I tried to send a handshake over my registered gateway, when I use your example and send it directly over the registered messsageChannel it works! Is there a reason why the gateway approach doesn't work? Thnx for the quick responses!

Comment: I changed my example to use a gateway and still see no problems - see EDIT2.